# Audio wave has no negative values

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

Long story short, I have an audio signal output in an int r, ie r has a value between 32768 and - 32768.

I tried to create a normalizing routine but for some reason the following code produces a half-wave, only the upper part is visible or in other words, everthing above 0, no negative values.

Here it is(dif is an int, dif_vorher, too)

```
if (r * 8 > 32768)
  dif = dif_vorher;
else if (r * 8 < -32768)
  dif = dif_vorher;
else
  dif = r * 8;        
dif_vorher = dif;
```

then it is being prepared to be written to a raw file:

```
if (dif != 0)
{
  putc((char) ( (unsigned)dif       & 0xff),ausgabe);
  putc((char) (((unsigned)dif >> 8) & 0xff),ausgabe);
}
```

This raw file has only upper values. I also tried

```
if (r * 8 > 32768)
  dif = 32768;
else if (r * 8 < -32768)
  dif = -32768;
else
  dif = r * 8;
```

and

```
if (r * 8 > 32768 || r * 8 < -32768)
  dif = -32768;
else
  dif = r * 8;
```

Same result, except when I use

```
if (r * 8 > 32768)
  dif = 32768;
else if (r * 8 < -32768)
  dif = -32768;
else
  dif = r * 8;
```

it is also distorted in the upper part.

Why is the negative part left out?

EDIT: I found that r * 8 has a maximum value of 524272 and a minimum value of 0. So r_max = 524272/8 = 65534; 65534/2 = 32767. So it seems that the value is shifted to avoid negative values by 32768.

Comment: Can you show some actual (typical) input data that is being processed by this code?

Comment: First look guess you are casting it wrongly `putc((char) ( (unsigned)dif & 0xff),ausgabe);`

Comment: @ryyker I just did this when I read your reply. I get no negative values surprisingly but only a maximum of 524272.

Comment: Just deleted my answer. It did not address your issue.  I can see you are trying to prepare the data by only using the least significant 8 bits, so that it will fit into char,  Is that correct?

Comment: why are you keeping numbers from 32768 to -32768, then below only keeping the last 8 bits.  Why don't you just limit it above to 127 to -128 in the first place?

Comment: If char cuts out everything extending 127 - -128, it still produces very good audio files when just dif = r * 8 is being used if you overlook the clipping distortion. So there seems to be no error. Or the error is systematic and it only works by keeping a mistake that was made otherwise. Instead of tinkering with my solution, how would you approach it?

Comment: I am putting something together now.  It will solve the problem of losing your negative values I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key problem is that you are attempting to put
large numbers into a small space.  That is, without first
scaling the original numbers down to a size that will fit
comfortably into `char` storage, you are truncating some
of the information in the int data resulting in large 
negative values being interpreted as zeros.  By the way, if 
any of your negative values were > -128, I think the expression:
    `(char) ( (unsigned)dif       & 0xff)`  would have returned the negative value.

I am still not sure what exactly you are doing with that 
expression in the first place, i.e. if you already have
a scaled data value from your normalization function
(assuming it works), then would you not just put it into your
file?

In any case, as best I can tell, you are trying to accomplish 
two things, normalize (and here, I am assuming you mean scale, let me know if I am wrong)
a set of positive and negative data such
that it can be stored in `char`, then write that data using
`putc()` into a file.  If we solve the scaling problem,
then writing positive and negative results into a file will 
follow with no issue.

To scale the inputs ranging from +/- 32768 
down to something a char would hold, i.e. 127 to -128, 
you could multiply each value in your data by 
a ratio of those two values.  Something like:

```
char ScaleToChar(int x); //prototype

char ScaleToChar(int x)
{
    int a = x;
    float ratio;
    //bound a:  -32768 to 32768
    if (abs(x) > 32768)
    {
        a = (x >= 0) ? (32768) : (-32768);
    }
    //scale x: -128 to 127
    ratio = (a <= 0) ? (128.0/32768.0) : (127.0/32768);

    return (char)(a * ratio);
}
```

Using this, your lines:

```
  putc((char) ( (unsigned)dif       & 0xff),ausgabe);
  putc((char) (((unsigned)dif >> 8) & 0xff),ausgabe);
```

Would become

```
  putc(ScaleToChar(dif),ausgabe);
```

(I do not know what you are doing with the second call, but if needed, you could do the shift and & op, then call `ScaleToChar()`)

***[EDIT]***

Rather than the scaling approach I originally suggested, I think what you are going to have to do is filter the waveform.  That is, increment through your array of data, and when the waveform approaches the limit (either negative or positive limit) use some history from, say, the last 10 to 15 array values, to determine how you should trend the potentially errant values in such a way that they never violate the limit.  This way, the bulk of your data will never have to be touched.  This will allow fidelity to be be maintained (unlike the scaling approach), at the same time, changes to any modified data will be limited to those data falling within some pre-determined, region extending around the center of the violating section of waveform, and the modification would be limited to values approximating values in the surrounding neighborhood of non-errant values.

A FIR filter approach comes to mind, but something as simple as a running average would also work.  The values of your data not in danger of violating the limits would never have to be touched by the filter.  In concept, this approach does not sound too complicated.  However, as I began to think how I would solve it, I realized that you could get pretty complicated (eg. applying ***[Kalman filter](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/media/pdf/kalman_intro.pdf)*** for predictive analysis).  With that said, it can also be kept pretty simple, i.e. such as the simple running average.

Comment: Re: normalizing. What I mean by this is that I have a raw wave file consisting of crackle sometimes(which spikes the amplitude and is not useful for measurement) and desired signal. Let's say the highest amplitude of the desired signal is 20 % of the max signal, ie 6554. Therefore I want to multiply the input signal with 5. That in turn increases the already clipping crackle even more. So I need to do something with that. My idea is to limit every value that returns from the calculation (value_source * 5) and that is greater than 32768 to be 32768 (and vv for negative values).

Comment: okay, I see.  I am at work right now, but will work on modifying my code such that it conforms to your description of normalizing.  I realized, once I thought about it, that my method of _scaling_ the inputs was going to diminish the fidelity of the sound. I will get back to this later.   The solution will be simply remembering that the sign of a binary number is kept in the most significant bit.  Therefore, &'ing the value with 0xff, will essentially eliminate that sign bit.  Will fix later, if you haven't already.  Thanks for the vote!

Comment: To avoid further confusion, here is the complete code I use for this: http://pastebin.com/kwrRhbsi  Datei is part of the filename that is later(line 4) connected to a whole RAW-filename. The RAW-file is 44100 Hz, 16 Bit, Stereo.

Comment: I am going to edit my answer above with comment on how I would approach you solution given my understanding of your question (to this point.)